# Build failed due to validation errors

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone app. I am using **Linq to Sql** with WCF application. I have drag and drop the tables and store procedure in **Model.dbml**. I am stuck with following error.

> Error 1   Build failed due to validation errors in E:\path\Model.dbml.  Open the file and resolve the issues in the Error List, then try rebuilding the project.

I am not getting about this error. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

**.dbml** is related to **Linq to Sql** Classes. It's not relevant to ADO.NET or Windows Phone and for sure it's fully supported in WCF and often the recommanded approach.

Linq to Sql uses a database-first approach where you have the database and model your classes after the DB schema. It's a completely client side thing : a set of information about your tables in the database and how you're going to map them to .NET objects. The DBML file is mapping that defines your classes based on your database schema.

DBML Validation is a specific task in the Build process.

To see the error, open the dbml file (desginer) and check **Error List Tab**. It's a compilation error and not a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Frist `clean` your project and next `build` it.
I had this problem.